# Trouble downloading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This error massage pops when the components download is finished. There are four components that it can't install. I have tried to retry the download but it keeps failing to download these components again, and I also tried to run the setup as administrator.

Do I have to download them from the internet outside of the Android Studio setup, and if so, how? What other solutions can you suggest to me?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a network issue. What happens if you access those URLs via a web browser?

Comment: a file start downloading...but i don't know how to locate it into android studio